# It's there any way to get v-model's variable name in the parent component from a child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

For case below, when I customize a vue component of radio, I can use model option to get the v-model value which should be a string '1'.How can I get its variable name 'radio1' in the child? It's there any way?

the child component

```
<template>
  <input type="radio" v-model="prop" :value="value">
</template>
<script>
export default {
  model: {
    prop: "prop"
  },
  props: {
    prop: {
      default: ''
    },
    value: {
      default: ''
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

the parent use this component

```
<template>
  <div>
    <radio-component v-model="radio1" value="1"></radio-component>
    <radio-component v-model="radio1" value="2"></radio-component>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import radioComponent from './radio'
export default {
  components: {
    radioComponent
  },
  data () {
    return {
      radio1: '1'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: do you need to get model name or model value?

Comment: actually i want to get model name and bind it to the attribute of input as a name

Comment: then you should change your subject to point out your final goal for this issue :)

Answer (score 0):

You can emit an event with any name you want, so in the child you can write:

```
<input type="radio" @input="$emit('prop', prop)" v-model="prop" :value="value">
```

Then in the parent you can do:

```
<radio-component v-model="radio1" @prop="doSomething" value="1" name="nameValue"></radio-component>
.
.
.
data(){
   return {
     nameValue: null
    }
methods: {
doSomthing(prop){
   this.nameValue = prop
}
}
```